# newlines introduced by echo/printf while echo'ing array entry populated with file's column

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am checking my shell line on the shell before putting it in the shell script

```
$ cat file.csv | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' 
"test1 test2 test1"
"test2 test3 test100"
"test3 test4 test3"
```

whereas , in the script I am populating
all the above info into the array 
like this

```
arr=(`cat file.csv | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }'`)
for v in ${arr[@]}
do
    echo $v
done
```

It echo's me like this

```
"test1
test2
test1"
"test2 
test3 
test100"
"test3 
test4 
test3"
```

I want the array to be populated with , for e.g., entry like this :

```
"test1 test2 test1"
```

and not

```
"test1
test2
test1"
```

Comment: Sorry for confusion - I have edited the Question.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is the way bash determines what seperates each element of the array. By default it uses any character in the IFS vairable, which defaults to whitespace ie tabs spaces and newlines. As each element of your array contains whitespace this cannot be a part of the IFS if you want it to work properly. Therefore if you try:

```
root@host$ cat x.txt
blah,one two three,blah
blah,four five six, blah
root@server$ IFS=$'\n' arr=( $(  awk -F',' '{print $2 }' x.txt ) ) ## no need to cat into awk it can take a filename argument to read from
root@server$ for v in ${arr[@]};do echo "$v";done
one two three
four five six
```

you should see it output correctly

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how the array is filled, The original question uses quoted values in the csv, which get ignored by the assignment to the array.

Note that in the assignment of arr, the $( ) bit is quoted with double quotes.

```
file.csv="test1 test2 test1","test2 test3 test100","test3 test4 test3"

$ arr=( "$( awk -F, 'print $2}' file.csv)" )
```

Will correctly put the values in the array,

```
$ for f in ${arr[@]}; do echo $f; done
```

will print out the second value:

```
"test2 test3 test100"
```

The quotes of the second value are still there, whether you use echo $f or echo "$f", doesn't matter.